# Getting Flickr RecentActivity images

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr, objectiveflickr

I want to retrieve Recent Activity images from flickr application, please any one suggest me how to retrieve that. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way of doing this but I will provide you a way to retrieve recent pictures on flickr. Standford iTunesU had a few lectures that related to this. I am getting almost all of my information from them. Here is a link to the course material:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

For the basic, non multithreaded version look under lecture 10 and download **Shutterbug Universal**. You will also need a flickr API key which you can currently get here:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html

I will attempt to outline for you though how to go about completing your request, especially since either of those links may not be around for long.

You will want to create a class `FlickrFetcher` or something, then have a public class method

```
 + (NSArray *)latestGeoreferencedPhotos;
```

Implementation

```
+ (NSArray *)latestGeoreferencedPhotos
{
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=500&license=1,2,4,7&has_geo=1&extras=original_format,tags,description,geo,date_upload,owner_name,place_url"];
    return [[self executeFlickrFetch:request] valueForKeyPath:@"photos.photo"];
}
```

Where `executeFlickrFetch` is implemented:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)executeFlickrFetch:(NSString *)query
{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=%@", query, FlickrAPIKey];
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
    if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
    return results;
}
```

You will need to get your API key and either define it (`#define FlickrAPIKey @"myAPIkey"`) or just directly insert it here.

In the Standford course they call `latestGeoreferencedPhotos` from a TVC subclass and set an array of photos in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// photos is a defined property
self.photos = [FlickrFetcher latestGeoreferencedPhotos];
```

Then in the setter for photos they reload a tableView that presents the images:

```
- (void)setPhotos:(NSArray *)photos
{
    _photos = photos;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

`photos` is now an array of dictionaries where so you can access specific image data by doing things like:

```
return [self.photos[row][@"title"] description]; // description because could be NSNull
```

I did find a github resource that may be valuable:
https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr.
I did not look into it much but it is probably worth checking into!

Your question did not provide much detail so I hope that this answer is sufficient for your needs.